# Android: How to change Screen Resolution in Max?

Tags: screen, resolution

In settings of device Max Screen Resolution written: 1280 x 800 pixels.
But display.getWidth() display.getHeight() write X = 320  Y = 512

How I can change resolution for Global and Local apps ???

```
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); 
widthScreen = display.getWidth();
heightScreen = display.getHeight();
makeToast(String.valueOf(widthScreen) + " / " + heightScreen,"","",""); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest file need specify minimum API Level:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Then app work in Max Screen Mode